# How to overlay elements with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I simply want to create an Autocomplete element on the top where the suggestion list is not shifting down the remaining elements im my Layout.

I could try to wrap the `Entry` and `ListView` in an `AbsoluteLayout` container, but for me this sounds not like a clean solution. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a Grid you can overlay stuff and set if should go left, right, center etc.. The last one to be added will be on top, in your case Entry.

Answer (score 11):

Been using Grid all the time until it started randomly crashing with complicated layouts.

Anyway the solution is to use an AbsoluteLayout.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout

Example of 2 centered overlayed items:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        
     <BoxView
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"          
              BackgroundColor="Red"
              HeightRequest="100"
              WidthRequest="100"/>
    
     <ActivityIndicator
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"          
              IsRunning="True"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

XAML Tips:

FillAndExpand XY:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
```

Center XY:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1"     
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Vertical Center, Horizontal Fill:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, -1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Vertical End, Horizontal Center

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 1, -1, -1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Vertical Start, Horizontal Center

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0, -1, -1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Vertical Start, Horizontal Start

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, -1, -1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to overlay elements you can use "Absolute" and/or "Relative" Layout.

There is workaround for overlaying using "Grid". In order to do that you need to put your elements or "containers" in same Row/Cell.

Here is example:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="test" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="overlay" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```