# How To Use Different Alignments for Elements in XAML AbsoluteLayout (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In the following XAML, I have a Frame that contains an AbsoluteLayout that contains an Image and a Label.  I want the Image to be left justified and the Label to be centered (in the entire AbsoluteLayout object).  Here is my XAML:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource App.Raindrops.png}" 
               WidthRequest="40" 
               HeightRequest="60" />
        <Label Text="Sprinkle" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"  
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               TextColor="White" 
               FontSize="36"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

No matter what HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions I use, I always get the following...

[image]

Notice that the label is not centered.  Am I using the wrong layout?  Am I missing, or using some wrong, attributes?

I am building the application in Visual Studio as a Xamarin.Forms app, and the deployment is being done to the standard Visual Studio Android emulator.

Comment: you use an AbsoluteLayout when you want granular control over where your elements are placed.  From what you're describing you would be better off with a horizontal StackLayout

Comment: StackLayout doesn't work because I can't center the label across the entire area, i.e. overlapping the image and the text can't be done.

Comment: you said you wanted the image on the left and the label in the center.  That's not overlapping.  You should be able to do that easily with a StackLayout

Comment: Yes.  I want the label centered across the entire frame.  If I use a StackLayout with Horizontal orientation, the image is displayed first on the left, then the label takes up the remaining space.  The text in label can then be centered but it's not in the center of the frame, only in the center of the label.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723913/how-to-overlay-elements-with-xamarin-forms) (which also has a great discussion on overlaying in XAML).  The modified XAML is:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Image 
            Source="{local:ImageResource App.Raindrops.png}" 
            WidthRequest="50" 
            HeightRequest="60"/>
        <Label 
            Text="Sprinkle" 
            TextColor="White" 
            FontSize="36"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

... and the result is this ...

[image]

... which is exactly what I wanted.

By the way, I came across this little tidbit in the  documentation page for AbsoluteLayout:
[image]