# What keeps Views/UIViews from being drawn outside their ViewCell/UITableViewCell

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to replicate Instagram's zoom feature on their list of videos on iOs using xamarin.forms.

I have a xamarin.forms ListView (actually a modified [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)) and I've been successful for the most part except for the fact that when I'm zooming, the zoomed view (an AVPlayerViewController) zooms fine but **cannot extend beyond the size of the cell that contains it** so it gets clipped. The effect is achieved by a simple UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer and applying the appropriate Transform/Scale using CGAffineTransform.

[You can see the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3z58.gif)

From what I understand, the clipsToBounds property is what keeps views confined to their parent's frame so I tried:

- setting clipsToBounds to false (even though that's supposed to be the default value) in the renderer and recursively to all the views' .Parent properties.
- setting it to false in the default ViewCell renderer.
- setting Xamarin's IsClippedToBounds to false at the xaml level.

Instagram also seems to blur the background of the zoomed video (as it is being zoomed) which would indicate that they've somehow moved the video view out of the cell and into some other temporary fullscreen view.

So I'm looking for some general guidance; is my understanding of clipsToBounds wrong? What is keeping the view from being drawn outside of its UITableViewCell? Should I approach this from a different angle? I'm at my wits' end, thanks in advance.

Comment: **1)** Its easier for people to give useful help, if you *show the xaml/code* of the ListView, includng the ItemTemplate. And your iOS custom renderer. **2)** *"... moved the video view out of the cell and into some other temporary fullscreen view."* - This is what you want to do.  See [How to overlay elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723913/how-to-overlay-elements-with-xamarin-forms?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). Use `IsVisible` true/false to control when the zooming overlay is seen.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve There's too much code involved and I'm not sure what is causing this behaviour to narrow it down though I understand that it makes it harder to help! As for the overlaying, I can show a view over the ListView when the zooming starts but how would I transfer the view I'm trying to zoom on, from the cell to the overlay, as seamlessly as they do it on Instagram? (and then return it once it's done zooming)

Comment: you mean use PinchGesture to let the view over the listview?

Comment: *"how would I transfer the view I'm trying to zoom on, from the cell to the overlay, as seamlessly as they do it on Instagram?"* - It won't be the *same* view. Instead, it will be a different view, displaying the same data. I would find the view, determine where it is on the screen, then position a view on top of it, on a RelativeLayout overlay, using pixel coordinates. This is an advanced topic. It might take days to get it seamless. Maybe [Drag and Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop) has hooks that would help.

Comment: *There's too much code involved"* - When something isn't working right, and there is too much code to figure it out, the *first step* is to make the *simplest* example you can, that demonstrates the problem. The example doesn't have to be useful to you as is - it should be as simple as you can make it, yet fails to extend beyond the bounds. Actually, the starting point would be to make a trivial example where you **can** extend beyond a view's bounds. There's probably some example that shows that. Then you experiment with adding different xaml to it, until you break it.