# Xamarin Forms is it possible to make different shapes for buttons or must I use imagebutton?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I really want to know if it's possible to make the custom shapes of a button to be the same as in the image, or must I use images?

The reason I don't want to use images is due to making sure they're properly scaling on each device where adding a custom button with text on top will always scale correctly to the device size.

After doing some research I couldn't find anything on this as I'm assuming this is another impossible thing that Xamarin.Forms don't support. Or potentially its possible with creating custom renderers?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/create

Comment: you can add a gesture recognizer to any element to make it behave like a button

Comment: @Jason I'm well aware of that but I would like it to be a button element with that kind of shape, is that possible? Or must I use imageButtons with a gesture recognizer? That is what I'm trying to ask. The ability of having Button element is that I can have custom renderers for Text and not an image which is annoying to change if we want to update for an event. Thanks

Comment: You can create your shape on Figma, and then export the SVG paths into a [Xamarin Forms shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/) and finally add a gesture recognizer to it

Comment: Make a custom control which contains text (from string, not an image), on top of a shape. Use a single cell grid, containing a shape and a label.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve could you possibly provide an example? Thanks

Comment: [How to overlay elements with Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31723913/199364). Or search `xamarin two elements overlaid on top of each other`.